# List tile is not showing all data in flutter?

Tags: list, flutter, dart

The full list is not showing and I'm not getting any error.
[I'm getting this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8OEH6.png)

```
class _RandomWordsState extends State<RandomWords> {
 final List<String> _suggestions = [' Cleaning a', 'cleaning b','Cleaning c','Cleaning d','cleaning e'];
 final _saved = <String>{};
 final _biggerFont = TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0);

 Widget _buildSuggestions() {
  return ListView.builder(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
    itemCount: _suggestions.length,
    itemBuilder:  (context, i) {
      if (i.isOdd) return Divider();

      final index = i ~/ 2;

      return _buildRow(_suggestions[index]);
    });
   }
```

This is the list I am passing but not getting the full list as an output.
Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your manual logic of adding dividers is messing with your normal logic of displaying items. You *could* debug it and figure out where it goes wrong. It would be a good learning experience.

However, if you want a divider between items, don't try to do it yourself, use `ListView.separated` (see [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView/ListView.separated.html)) instead of `ListView.builder`.

Answer (score 0):

Use List.separated, see the documentation for more details.

```
class _RandomWordsState extends State<RandomWords> {
 final List<String> _suggestions = [' Cleaning a', 'cleaning b','Cleaning c','Cleaning d','cleaning e'];
 final _saved = <String>{};
 final _biggerFont = const TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0);

 Widget _buildSuggestions() {
  return ListView.separated(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
    itemCount: _suggestions.length,
    itemBuilder:  (context, i) => _buildRow(_suggestions[i]) , separatorBuilder: (context, index) => const Divider(),);
   }
}
```